# How is quantum physics translated into the world of electronics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

I remember watching a documentary about early works in quantum physics and how it was essential to the microelectronics revolution and the invention of the transistor. What part exactly helped? Is there a source on technical aspects that lead to such development?

Comment: Might [hsm.se] be better suited for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One word: Semiconductors.

Semiconductor physics cannot be explained using classical physics. One needs to understand the [electronic band structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure) of these materials in order to engineer various devices (e.g., p-n junctions, p-n-p junctions etc.) using them. Without such basic devices we won't be able to engineer modern electronic devices.

Comment: Very helpful indeed! Thanks a lot for the quick answer.

Comment: And, if we are talking of _modern_ devices, then in addition to p-n junctions one should also mention [heterostructures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterojunction).